# Extract from arrays - Not all code paths return a value

Tags: c#, arrays, extract

I'm trying to extract even number from an array.

I feel like I'm almost getting it, but I keep getting this error and don't know what to do.

> (int[])': not all code paths return a value

I know I need a return value but I want to return nothing, but just the values as per the if statement.

The If statement is basically:

```cs
if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
```

so this is the condition for me to get even values in the array, which is what I want.

Then now I need to return something apparently, based on my research. But I just want to return the even values as gotten from the if statement.
My current code:

```cs
static int[] ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr)
{
    
    for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
    {
        if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
        {
            Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");
        }               
        
    }
    
    // so I need a return value here? what do I return? 
    //I dont want to return arr; cause it'll just repeat the arr. 
}
```

EDIT:

This is what I want to get (the bold value):

[ 4 1 2 5 6 1 3 ] -> **[ 4 2 6 ]**

The sample array is on the left.

I tried to return int[];

but it is giving me more errors?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3J7A.png)

*Question has been solved. Thank you everyone! :)*

Comment: Hint: your method has a return type of `int[]`. Did you *want* to return an array of integers, or not? If not, why have you specified that as the return type?

Comment: If you don't want to return anything don't use `int[]` as the return type. Change it to `void`

Comment: @JonSkeet I want to return the even numbers in the array so like for example if the array is [1 2 3 4] I want to just get 2 4. Hopefully this answers your question sorry if I didn't.

Comment: So how do you want to return those values? If you want to return them in an array, you'll need to create a new array with only the right values in. Or you could return a list. Or you could use `yield return` and return an `IEnumerable<int>`...

Comment: Are you sure you want to return `int[]` ? If you just do `Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");` in your if statement, you return nothing, so you can declare your function as `static void ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr)`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok here is the thing I can't change: static int[] ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr) { cause that is the default code in my assignment, so is there a way that I can work with int[]?

Comment: What is the assignment? If it asks for an int array, it means you *have* to return such an array with some meaningful values. We can't guess what you want

Comment: `I'm trying to extract even number from an array.` that means you need to *return* the even numbers, not print them

Comment: @SalvationCode if `static int[] ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr)` is the default code, you have to return `int[]`. It can be empty if nothing have been found. I suggest you to use `List<int>` to temporary store numbers you found, then convert it to `int[]` before returning result

Comment: Instead of `Console.Write(arr[i] + " ");` add the number to a list or array and return that at the end.

Comment: @SalvationCode Are you actually allowed to use Linq in your answer? It sounds like an assignment where you need to write all the code yourself.

Comment: I don't know how to use lists yet... haven't learnt it. I can't use Where as it's showing me an error that says no accessible extension method (sounds like a whole new can of worms). And... I don't know what is Linq sorry, yeah we are supposed to write the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're supposed to be implementing this using low-level code which doesn't require Linq or even `List<T>`.

You can do this using just loops and a results array using the following algorithm:

1. Determine how many numbers there will be in the returned array. You can do this by looping over the input array and counting the number of even numbers. You need to know this because you want to create an array the correct size to hold all the results.
2. Create a results array of the size that you just calculated.
3. Loop over the input again and this time add each even number to the results array. You can use a counter (an integer variable) as an index which you increment after adding each even number to the results, so that you know where each new number should go in the results array.
4. Finally, you can return the results array.

Here's a sample implementation - read the code carefully to make sure that you understand each step.

```
static int[] ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr)
{
    // (1) Count how many even numbers there are.

    int n = 0;

    foreach (int number in arr) 
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            ++n;
        }
    }

    // (2) Create a result array of the correct size.

    int[] result = new int[n];

    // (3) Copy into the array all the even numbers.
    // Here we use i to index where the next even number should go in the results.

    int i = 0;

    foreach (int number in arr)
    {
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            result[i] = number;
            ++i; // Next even number will go into the next result element.
        }
    }

    // (4) Return the results;

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Oh my man this is right! Thank you so much!! I will read it carefully and try to understand thank u :,)

Answer (score 0):

You said in comments you can't remove `static int[] ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr)` because it is the default code in your assignment, so you have to return an `int[]`. It can be an empty array if nothing has been found.
In C# you can't add elements to `int[]` object because you can't change their length, so I suggest you to use List to temporary store numbers you found, then convert it to int[] before returning result:

```
    static int[] ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr)
    {
        List<int> result = new();
        
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] % 2 == 0)
            {
                result.Add(arr[i]);
                Console.Write(arr[i] + " "); // Optional
            }

        }
        
        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

You can also use `foreach` to iterate over your array, because you don't need the indices of the number, but only the value. I think this is the most understandable if you are new at coding:

```
static int[] ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr)
    {
        List<int> result = new();

        foreach (int number in arr)
        {
            if (number % 2 == 0)
            {
                result.Add(number);
                Console.Write(number + " "); // Optional
            }

        }

        return result.ToArray();
    }
```

Simpler, you can use `.Where`:

```
static int[] ExtractEvenNumber(int[] arr)
    {
        return arr.Where(number => number % 2 == 0).ToArray();
    }
```

Comment: Hi kind sir, thanks for helping me out. It doesn't work on my end :,,C . I can't use .Where as it's showing me an error that says no accessible extension method. and the first one that you showed, it says it requires C# like version 9 and apparently I have version 8, which is :(

Comment: @SalvationCode In this case I suggest you follow Matthew Watson's answer, but keep in mind that it is not optimized (you go through the list twice doing the same operation) and the code is really heavy. Even to educate yourself this solution looks really heavy. I think you'll soon discover the lists and you can come back to this post to better understand their point :)